# polymer binded value can't change

Tags: javascript, data-binding, firebase, polymer

How can i change a button content when i click it? 
in a function can i change the binded value?

```
<dom-module id="my-facebook-login-button">
<template>
<paper-button on-click="facebookLogin">{{loginButton}}</paper-button>
</template>
</dom-module>
<script>
(function() {
Polymer({
  is: 'my-facebook-login-button',
  properties: {
    loginButton: {
      type: String,
      value: 'Login with facebook',
      notify: true 
    }
  },
facebookLogin: function() {
var ref = new Firebase("https://sizzling-heat-4021.firebaseio.com/");
ref.authWithOAuthPopup("facebook", function (error, authData) {
if (error) {
  console.log("Login Failed!", error);
} else {
  console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);    
    app.user=authData;
    this.loginButton='Loged in';
}
});
},
});

})();
</script>
```

this.loginButton='Loged in' dont change the button content

Comment: Just a blind shoot, does `this.loginButton.value = 'Loged in';` works ?

Comment: Did you try to bind `this` in your `function (error, authdata)`? Like `function() {}.bind(this)`?

Answer (score 0):

Neil has the right answer in his comment. use bind. Updated function below:

```
facebookLogin: function() {
  var ref = new Firebase("https://sizzling-heat-4021.firebaseio.com/");
  ref.authWithOAuthPopup("facebook", function (error, authData) {
    if (error) {
      console.log("Login Failed!", error);
    } else {
      console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);    
      app.user=authData;
      this.loginButton='Logged in';
    }
  }.bind(this));
},
```